# Can I treat int and float the same in my Cucumber Steps?

Tags: cucumber

I'm trying to write tests for a Tuple class that I'm writing in Ruby (this is an exercise to learn both Ruby and Gherkin).  So one of my Scenarios creates a Tuple with float values:

```
Scenario: A tuple with w=1.0 is a point
  Given a ← tuple[4.3, -4.2, 3.1, 1.0]
   Then a.x = 4.3
    And ...
```

For the `Given` step, cucumber suggests the following:

```
Given("a ← tuple[{float}, {float}, {float}, {float}]") do |float, float2, float3, float4|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

which I implemented as:

```
Given("a ← tuple[{float}, {float}, {float}, {float}]") do |float, float2, float3, float4|
  tuple_a = Tuple.new(float, float2, float3, float4)
end
```

Great.  Now I want another scenario which happens to pass integers to the Tuple:

```
 Scenario: Adding two tuples
   Given a ← tuple[3, -2, 5, 1]
   ...
```

And Cucumber suggests:

```
Given("a ← tuple[{int}, {int}, {int}, {int}]") do |int, int2, int3, int4|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

But my implementation is in Ruby; I don't really care if i'm passing `int`s or `float`s to `Tuple.new()`.  The `Given` step I implemented first which expects floats would work the same for `int`s, but Cucumber won't use that; it wants me to implement it again with `int` params.  I could just use float arguments, e.g. `Given a ← tuple[3.0, -2.0, 5.0, 1.0]`, but that's kind of annoying.  Is my only option to define a custom `ParameterType`?  That would entail a regexp that matches both integers and floats; will that take priority over the existing `int` and `float` types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using unit test tools for this sort of thing e.g. rspec, minitest etc. they are a much better fit.

Scenarios are useful when you can express things in a language that is not technical and abstract. Your scenarios are technical and concrete and much harder to read and write.

An analogy is trying to write mathematical expressions in a natural langauge.

`(3+5)^3` is much simpler and more precise than, `add 5 to 3 and then cube the total`

The art of learning Gherkin is how to write simple clear scenarios that describe a particular behaviour. It is not about using multiple params, complex regex's, large tables and multiple examples. You are learning the wrong things if you want to learn how to Cuke and do BDD. You are using the wrong tool if you want to learn ruby and write tests for things like a Tuple class.